# check if a directory is already created python

Tags: python, python-2.7

A very basic question, I have a module that creates directories on the fly, however, sometimes I want to put more than one file in a dir. If this happens, python rises an exception and says that the dir is already created, how can I avoid this and check if the dir is already created or not?

The save module looks something like this:

```
def createdirs(realiz):
# Create all the necessary directories                                                                           
path = "./doubDifferences_probandamp_realiz%d/"%realiz
os.mkdir(path,0755)
directory = os.path.split(path)[0]
return directory
```

On the main program, I have this:

```
for realiz in range(1,1000):
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(i+1,i+4):
            ...
            dirspaths = mod_savefile.createdirs(realiz)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could go for a try except:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(path,0755)
except OSError:
    pass
```

“Easier to ask forgiveness than permission !”

Also this method is more safe that testing the directory before doing `mkdir`. Indeed, it is fairly possible that between the two os call implied by `ispath` and `mkdir` the directory may have been created or destroyed by another thread.

Comment: I used    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
but I don't know why this works also and what's exactly the difference

Comment: user2820579: `os.path.exists(path)` return `True` if there is something at path, not paying attention whether its a directory or a file.

Answer (score 3):

This should cover you. Just test if it is a directory before you try to create it.

```
if not os.path.isdir(path)
   os.mkdir(path,0755)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways. Either use [`os.path.isdir`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.isdir) function:

```
import os.path 

def createdirs(realiz):
    # Create all the necessary directories
    path = "./doubDifferences_probandamp_realiz%d/"%realiz
    if not os.path.isdir(path):  # if not exists
        os.mkdir(path,0755)      # create it
    directory = os.path.split(path)[0]
    return directory
```

Or handle the exception.